# Can I wield an enchanted spiked shield and magic weapon in the same hand?

Tags: dnd-4e, shield

The Adventurer's Vault states that the spiked shield:

> can be enchanted as a magic shield or a magic weapon, but not both. A spiked shield enchanted as a magical weapon does not occupy a character's magic item arms slot. (pg.10)

This is unclear about whether it also takes up a "weapons" slot.

Could I wield an enchanted spiked shield on one arm and hold a magical weapon in the respective hand? I'm aware I couldn't attack with the weapon, but it may be useful for its property.

E.g. would a character wearing a rhythm blade spiked shield and holding a quicksilver dagger on the same limb benefit from both their respective properties?

Comment: is the shield a buckler?

Comment: I asked a [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59673/12011) about needing to wield or just hold magical weapons in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it takes up that hand's weapon slot (because it already did).

Basically, you can *either* have an enchanted shield or an enchanted arm slot item. You can also have a weapon in each hand.

You can't wield another item in that hand (you can *hold* an item, but not wield it). Thus you can't otherwise wield a magic weapon in that hand so you've got that.

The only thing this rule does is allow for a magic arm slot item when you otherwise would not be able to have one (because you're wearing a magic shield).

Comment: To clarify, items held in your hands usually do not take up your arms slot; Your arms slot is more for bracers and stuff like that. I suspect the reason for pointing out that magical shields don't take up an arms slot is because shields are strapped to your arm and some players might wonder about it.

Comment: @GMJoe not quite. Magical shields *normally* take up your arm slot. If this shield is enchanted as a weapon, it doesn't

Comment: Gah, you're right - I should've proofread and fact-checked.

Comment: Thanks! If I can't wield a weapon, would an implement work for granting a property?
E.g., rhythm blade spiked shield, bracers of mighty striking, rod of corruption. 
Also - can I use the power of an item that I'm holding, but not wielding? Bradaman's weapon, for example.

Comment: @selekate I'd have to check the wording, but probably not. Most things usually say "wield" rather than "hold". That said you can use your *other hand* to wield another weapon.

Comment: @Selekate Rhythm Blade's effect specifically says 'wield'. If you have the shield enchanted as a rhythm blade, then that's fine because you're wielding it, however shield bonuses don't stack. If you have a rhythm dagger in that same hand, you won't get the bonus because you're not wielding it.